# Salesforce Named Credential HMAC merge function \n new line not work in value

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to make an api integration using named credential with custom provider, making use of the merge function BASE64ENCODE HMAC for a signing value

in summary, I am not getting the same value as I can get from apex code.

This is an example of hmac generated by apex, which is fine and working:

```
String sampleText = 'my \n text';
Blob signatureBlob = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(sampleText), privateKeyBlob);
String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signatureBlob);
```

Here is the header formula merge field example:
NOTE: if I use just this value 'my \n text' , the merge fields and functions will reach to server without been translated.

```
String sampleText = 'my \\n text';
req.setHeader('Authorization', '{!BASE64ENCODE(HMAC(\'SHA-256\',BLOB(\'' + sampleText + '\'), BLOB($Credential.MyExtCred.privateKey)))}')
```

At the end comparing both values at the server level I am getting two hmac that are different.
Is this an issue in named credentials merge field or I am missing something ?

I tried both scenarios an expected same hmac result but where different